# How to align a dropdown menu under the parent item in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress, wp-nav-walker

I created a dropdown menu for my custom wordpress theme. To customize it I'm using a custom walker, but I don't know how to align the dropdown on the left and under the parent "Cours".

I'm a bit confused between the start_el and the start_lvl functions.

For now the dropdown seems to be built outside the parent, so I can't position it relatively to it.

[image: dropdown]

custom_nav.php

```
<?php

/**
 * Nav Menu API: Walker_Nav_Menu class
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Nav_Menus
 * @since 4.6.0
 */

/**
 * Core class used to implement an HTML list of nav menu items.
 *
 * @since 3.0.0
 *
 * @see Walker
 */
class my_nav_walker extends Walker {
    private $curItem;

    /**
     * What the class handles.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     * @var string
     *
     * @see Walker::$tree_type
     */
    public $tree_type = array( 'post_type', 'taxonomy', 'custom' );

    /**
     * Database fields to use.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     * @todo Decouple this.
     * @var array
     *
     * @see Walker::$db_fields
     */
    public $db_fields = array(
        'parent' => 'menu_item_parent',
        'id'     => 'db_id',
    );

    /**
     * Starts the list before the elements are added.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @see Walker::start_lvl()
     *
     * @param string   $output Used to append additional content (passed by reference).
     * @param int      $depth  Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
     * @param stdClass $args   An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
     */
    public function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = null ) {
        //var_dump($this->curItem);

        if ( isset( $args->item_spacing ) && 'discard' === $args->item_spacing ) {
            $t = '';
            $n = '';
        } else {
            $t = "\t";
            $n = "\n";
        }
        $indent = str_repeat( $t, $depth );

        // Default class.
        $classes = array( 'my-dropdown' );
        array_push($classes, strval($curItem->title));

        $my_id = '';
        if ($args->walker->has_children == true) {
            //var_dump($args->walker->curItem->ID);
            $my_id = $args->walker->curItem->ID;
        }
        /**
         * Filters the CSS class(es) applied to a menu list element.
         *
         * @since 4.8.0
         *
         * @param string[] $classes Array of the CSS classes that are applied to the menu `<ul>` element.
         * @param stdClass $args    An object of `wp_nav_menu()` arguments.
         * @param int      $depth   Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        //var_dump($args);
        $class_names = implode( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_submenu_css_class', $classes, $args, $depth ) );
        $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

        $output .= "{$n}{$indent}<div$class_names><button class=\"dropbtn\" onclick=\"toggleDropdown(".$my_id.")\"><img src=\"" . get_template_directory_uri() . "'/assets/images/chevron-down.svg'\"></button><div class=\"dropdown-content dropdown-content-".$my_id."\">{$n}";
    }

    /**
     * Ends the list of after the elements are added.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @see Walker::end_lvl()
     *
     * @param string   $output Used to append additional content (passed by reference).
     * @param int      $depth  Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
     * @param stdClass $args   An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
     */
    public function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = null ) {
        if ( isset( $args->item_spacing ) && 'discard' === $args->item_spacing ) {
            $t = '';
            $n = '';
        } else {
            $t = "\t";
            $n = "\n";
        }
        $indent  = str_repeat( $t, $depth );
        $output .= "$indent</div></div>{$n}";
    }

    /**
     * Starts the element output.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     * @since 4.4.0 The {@see 'nav_menu_item_args'} filter was added.
     *
     * @see Walker::start_el()
     *
     * @param string   $output Used to append additional content (passed by reference).
     * @param WP_Post  $item   Menu item data object.
     * @param int      $depth  Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
     * @param stdClass $args   An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
     * @param int      $id     Current item ID.
     */
    public function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = null, $id = 0 ) {
        $this->curItem = $item;

        if ( isset( $args->item_spacing ) && 'discard' === $args->item_spacing ) {
            $t = '';
            $n = '';
        } else {
            $t = "\t";
            $n = "\n";
        }

        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( $t, $depth ) : '';

        $classes   = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;

        /**
         * Filters the arguments for a single nav menu item.
         *
         * @since 4.4.0
         *
         * @param stdClass $args  An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         * @param WP_Post  $item  Menu item data object.
         * @param int      $depth Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $args = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_args', $args, $item, $depth );

        /**
         * Filters the CSS classes applied to a menu item's list item element.
         *
         * @since 3.0.0
         * @since 4.1.0 The `$depth` parameter was added.
         *
         * @param string[] $classes Array of the CSS classes that are applied to the menu item's `<li>` element.
         * @param WP_Post  $item    The current menu item.
         * @param stdClass $args    An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         * @param int      $depth   Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $class_names = implode( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args, $depth ) );
        $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

        /**
         * Filters the ID applied to a menu item's list item element.
         *
         * @since 3.0.1
         * @since 4.1.0 The `$depth` parameter was added.
         *
         * @param string   $menu_id The ID that is applied to the menu item's `<li>` element.
         * @param WP_Post  $item    The current menu item.
         * @param stdClass $args    An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         * @param int      $depth   Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-' . $item->ID, $item, $args, $depth );
        $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

        //$output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $class_names . '>';
        $output .= $indent . '';

        $atts           = array();
        $atts['title']  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? $item->attr_title : '';
        $atts['target'] = ! empty( $item->target ) ? $item->target : '';
        if ( '_blank' === $item->target && empty( $item->xfn ) ) {
            $atts['rel'] = 'noopener';
        } else {
            $atts['rel'] = $item->xfn;
        }
        $atts['href']         = ! empty( $item->url ) ? $item->url : '';
        $atts['aria-current'] = $item->current ? 'page' : '';

        /**
         * Filters the HTML attributes applied to a menu item's anchor element.
         *
         * @since 3.6.0
         * @since 4.1.0 The `$depth` parameter was added.
         *
         * @param array $atts {
         *     The HTML attributes applied to the menu item's `<a>` element, empty strings are ignored.
         *
         *     @type string $title        Title attribute.
         *     @type string $target       Target attribute.
         *     @type string $rel          The rel attribute.
         *     @type string $href         The href attribute.
         *     @type string $aria_current The aria-current attribute.
         * }
         * @param WP_Post  $item  The current menu item.
         * @param stdClass $args  An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         * @param int      $depth Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $atts = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', $atts, $item, $args, $depth );

        $attributes = '';
        foreach ( $atts as $attr => $value ) {
            if ( is_scalar( $value ) && '' !== $value && false !== $value ) {
                $value       = ( 'href' === $attr ) ? esc_url( $value ) : esc_attr( $value );
                $attributes .= ' ' . $attr . '="' . $value . '"';
            }
        }

        /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/post-template.php */
        $title = apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID );

        /**
         * Filters a menu item's title.
         *
         * @since 4.4.0
         *
         * @param string   $title The menu item's title.
         * @param WP_Post  $item  The current menu item.
         * @param stdClass $args  An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         * @param int      $depth Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $title = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_title', $title, $item, $args, $depth );
        
        

        $item_output  = $args->before;
        if ($args->walker->has_children == true) {
            //var_dump($item);
            $item_output .= '<a' . $attributes . ' class="' . $item->ID . '" onclick="toggleDropdown('.$item->ID.')">';
        } else {
            $item_output .= '<a' . $attributes . '>';
        }
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . $title . $args->link_after;
        if ($args->walker->has_children == true) {
            $item_output .= "<button class=\"dropbtn\" onclick=\"toggleDropdown(".$item->ID.")\"><img src=\"" . get_template_directory_uri() . "'/assets/images/chevron-down.svg'\"></button></a>";
        } else {
            $item_output .= '</a>';
        }
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        /**
         * Filters a menu item's starting output.
         *
         * The menu item's starting output only includes `$args->before`, the opening `<a>`,
         * the menu item's title, the closing `</a>`, and `$args->after`. Currently, there is
         * no filter for modifying the opening and closing `<li>` for a menu item.
         *
         * @since 3.0.0
         *
         * @param string   $item_output The menu item's starting HTML output.
         * @param WP_Post  $item        Menu item data object.
         * @param int      $depth       Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         * @param stdClass $args        An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         */
        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }

    /**
     * Ends the element output, if needed.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @see Walker::end_el()
     *
     * @param string   $output Used to append additional content (passed by reference).
     * @param WP_Post  $item   Page data object. Not used.
     * @param int      $depth  Depth of page. Not Used.
     * @param stdClass $args   An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
     */
    public function end_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = null ) {
        if ( isset( $args->item_spacing ) && 'discard' === $args->item_spacing ) {
            $t = '';
            $n = '';
        } else {
            $t = "\t";
            $n = "\n";
        }
        $output .= "{$n}";
        //$output .= "</li>{$n}";
    }

}


?>
```

my-scripts.js

```
function toggleDropdown(id, close) {
    console.log(id);
    setTimeout(function() {
        var myTopnav = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
        var dropdown = myTopnav.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content-" + id)[0];
        console.log(dropdown);
        if (dropdown) {
            console.log(dropdown.className);
            if (dropdown.className.search(" show-dropdown") === -1 && close != true) {
                dropdown.className += " show-dropdown";
            } else {
                dropdown.className = dropdown.className.replace(" show-dropdown", "");
            }
        }
    }, 0)
}
```

style.css

```
/*
Theme Name: XXX
*/
a:hover {
    opacity:0.5;
    transition:0.35s opacity;
}
.topnav-container img,
.topnav-top-subcontainer img {
    height:20px;
}
.topnav-container img:not(:first-child),
.topnav-top-subcontainer img:not(:first-child) {
    height:22px;
}
.topnav-container a:not(:first-child),
.topnav-top-subcontainer a:not(:first-child) {
    margin-left:10px;
}
.navbar-toggler {
    margin-bottom:10px;

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    
    nav {
        width:100%;
    }
    nav .container-fluid {
        padding:0;
    }
    .nav-item {
        text-align:center;
        background-color:lightgray;
    }
    .dropdown-menu {
        text-align:center;
    }
 
}

/* nav */
.navbar-icon {
    padding:20px;
}
.navbar-icon img {
    width:40px;
}
.navbar-icon .icon {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: url('./assets/images/menu.svg');
    transition:0.35s opacity;
}
.navbar-icon .icon.open {
    background: url('./assets/images/close.svg');
    background-size: 40px;
}
/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
.topnav {
    /*background-color: #333;*/
    overflow: hidden;
    width:100%;
    transition:0.35s height;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #888;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
    /*border-bottom:1px solid transparent;*/
    transition:0.35s color;
}

/* Add an active class to highlight the current page */
.active {
    /*background-color: #333;*/
    /*border-bottom-color:#333 !important;*/
    color: #333 !important;
}

/* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
.topnav .icon {
    display: none;
}

/* Dropdown container - needed to position the dropdown content */
.my-dropdown {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* Style the dropdown button to fit inside the topnav */
.my-dropdown .dropbtn, .dropbtn {
    font-size: 17px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #888;
    /*padding: 14px 16px;*/
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    transition:0.35s color;
}
.my-dropdown img {
    width:12px;
}

/* Style the dropdown content (hidden by default) */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

/* Style the links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: #888;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

/* Add a dark background on topnav links and the dropdown button on hover */
.topnav a:hover, .my-dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    /*background-color: #555;*/
    color: #333;
}

/* Add a grey background to dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}

/* Show the dropdown menu when the user moves the mouse over the dropdown button */
/*
.my-dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
display: block;
}
*/
.my-dropdown .show-dropdown {
    display: block;
}

.collapsing {
    height: 0;
}

/* When the screen is less than 600 pixels wide, hide all links, except for the first one ("Home"). Show the link that contains should open and close the topnav (.icon) */
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .topnav-container {
        padding-left:0 !important;
        padding-right:0 !important;
    }
    
    .my-dropdown {
        float: none;
    }
    .dropdown-content {
        background-color:#efefef;
    }
    .topnav a, .my-dropdown .dropbtn, .dropbtn {
        display: none;
    }
    .topnav a {
        float: none;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .topnav a.active {
        background-color:#333;
        color:#fff !important;
    }
    .topnav a.icon {
        float: right;
        display: block;
    }
}

/* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look good on small screens (display the links vertically instead of horizontally) */
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
    .topnav.responsive a.icon {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
    .topnav.responsive a {
        float: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .topnav.responsive .my-dropdown {float: none;}
    .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative;}
    .topnav.responsive .my-dropdown .dropbtn, .dropbtn {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post a live URL so that people can see the output directly.

Comment: @m4n0: Please do not invite to post live URLs to demonstrate a problem: Once the problem is fixed, the live-URL is useless. This is why a question on SO must be self-contained. If you're missing information in the question and you find that not helpful, comment and/or vote on the question according to the help section. Thanks!

Comment: @hakre Yes. But right now the code isn't sufficient. How can we debug the live code?

Comment: There should never be any need to debug live code on stackoverflow. demand the minimal, reproducible example. If it is not provided, vote on the question accordingly (down, close, then delete).

Comment: There is a screenshot of the ouput in my question that displays the misaligned dropdown.